# Can't upload file from Python requests, while CURL is work fine

Tags: python, curl, post, python-requests

I am trying to upload file to some api with this function:

```
 def upload_avatar(cred, file):
     headers = {'accept': '*/*', 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data', 'Authorization': f'Bearer {cred}'}
     files = { 'UploadForm[avatar]': ('image1.jpg', open('image1.jpg', 'rb'), 'image/jpg')}
     signup_req = requests.post(api_enpoint + "/profile/avatar", headers=headers, files=files)
     signup_req.raise_for_status()
```

And get `422 Client Error: Unprocessable entity for url: https://api_endpoint/v1/profile/avatar`

While CURL command works fine:

```
curl -v -X POST "https://api_endpoint/v1/profile/avatar" -H  "accept: */*" -H  "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -H "Authorization: Bearer SAME_LONG_TOKEN" -F "UploadForm[avatar]=@image1.jpg;type=image/jpeg"
```

What makes the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can drop the headers:

- `Accept: */*`
- `Content-Type: multipart/form-data`

`requests` takes care of it on it's own when you use its `json`, `data`, `files` kwargs ... and if you specify them it seems to freak it out.

I used [httpbin](https://httpbin.org) to compare the content of the `curl` and `requests` HTTP requests, it's a handy tool.

So for your example it would be:

```py
headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {cred}'} 
files = {'UploadForm[avatar]': ('image1.jpg', open('image1.jpg', 'rb'), 'image/jpeg')} 
signup_req = requests.post('https://httpbin.org/post', headers=headers, files=files)
```

Comment: Thanks man, it saved my day - almost 4 hours of work trying figure out the issue, and your solution to remove the "Content-Type" just saved my day. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import requests


def upload_avatar(cred, file):
    url = "https://api_endpoint/v1/profile/avatar"

    files = [
      (
          'UploadForm[avatar]',
          ('image1.jpg', open('image1.jpg', 'rb'),
           'application/octet-stream'))
    ]
    headers = {
      'accept': '*/*',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer SAME_LONG_TOKEN',
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      'Authorization': f'Bearer {cred}'
    }
    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, files=files)

    print(response.text)
```

Comment: unfortunately, result is the same